# Why is my ip changing in debian

Tags: windows, networking, debian, ip

Hello I live in a dorm and I have a laptop with a dualboot setup (Windows and Debian). Now the normal ip is 192.168.2.12 when in windows and in Debian usually too. But if I surf the web on the Debian computer i randomly get a new ip address 192.168.8.104 and I have to restart the machine. This same thing happens to a raspberry pi I connect to the network. Why is this happening and how do I stop it?

Comment: Sorry, voted to close as there is no question here, and insufficient information to the extent the question "why is my IP changing" can be deduced.

Comment: I edited it to include a question. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Maybe there’s a rogue DHCP server on the network. Professionally installed networks would remove these from the network automatically. Talk to your dorm manager about the problem.

Comment: If I do get on this strange network and I run an ipsweep there is a router connected to it. But i don't really know networks so I don't know if that is the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the IP which gets set on Windows is not statically assigned?
What happens if you go on and reconfigure the network in Debian in the same way? What connection is that, anyway? Wi-Fi or wired?

Comment: The "in debian" suggests that you've tried it on non-Debian systems and it doesn't happen there, which would be interesting. If you have, please report. If you haven't, the "in debian" isn't useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dorm network is probably badly configured, having two DHCP servers.
The DHCP protocol is first-come, first-serve. This means that when your computer
broadcasts a DHCP request for IP, it takes the first answer that it receives.

It seems that the two DHCP servers are at least configured without an overlap,
one serving IP addresses up to 100, and the other one above 100.

One of the DHCP servers is "closer" to you in the network sense, so that you
almost always get its answer first. Sometimes, because of some passing state of
the network, the other server answers first.
However, this is a temporary situation, and rebooting gets you again an answer
from the first server.

As a DHCP server may cache IP address allocation as associated with the
network card's MAC address, rebooting then gets your old address back.